# Let $n = p_1^{k_1} + p_2^{k_2} + ... + p_m^{k_m}$ how many ways can $n$ be written as a product of two positive integers

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n = p_1^{k_1} + p_2^{k_1} + ... + p_m^{k_m}$ where $p_1, p_2,...,p_m$ are distinct prime numbers and $k_1,k_2,...,k_m$ are positive integers. How many ways can $n$ be written as a product of two positive integers that have no common factors assuming that order matters (i.e., $8·15$ and $15·8$ are regarded as different)?

Don't know how to start this question.

Comment: Do you mean $n=p_1^{k_1}\times p_2^{k_2}\times\cdots \times p_m^{k_m}$? Because there is no way to solve the question with $+$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can choose some subset of the $m$ primes to put in one factor and the rest of primes go into the other factor.  Once you choose the primes in each factor everything else is determined, up to the order of the two factors, because the full power of each prime has to go the one factor only so that the two factors share no common divisor.  Thus for each subset of $m$ primes you have two factorizations, one for each order of the two factors.  Now for each subset, its complement will give the same two factors.  There are $2^m$ subsets of $m$ things.  So there are $\frac12\cdot2^m$ total ways to choose the two factors and then since order matters we have to multiply by two. So the total number is $2^m$, according to your criteria.